# How can I tell which Silverlight Popup (or ChildWindow) is topmost?

Tags: silverlight, popup, hittest, childwindow

I am trying to hit test in Silverlight applications to find the elements under the mouse cursor.

Normally `VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates` works for this. If there is a `Popup` open I need to pass in the popup to the hit testing method. If there are multiple popups open, I need to determine the correct (topmost) popup to pass in.

Is there any reliable way to determine which `Popup` is topmost? I'm doing this in an assembly that may be loaded after the `Popup`s have been opened, so I can't rely on tracking the order in which they are opened.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the new `VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups` call returns the open `Popup`s in order from bottom to top (or least recently to most recently opened?). So that does what I need.

Posting this answer in case anyone else runs into the same issue.